# Incremental bullet point functionality for pdf exports

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, knitr, xaringan

I've been creating html slides using `xaringan` but recently decided I wanted to annotate them on my ipad.  I've been testing out the pdf conversion functionality documented here: https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki/Export-Slides-to-PDF. I was wondering if incremental bullet points are supported in any of the pdf conversion tools? I was hoping incremental bullets would split across slides when converting to pdf (i.e. the way beamer handles incremental bullets).

I tried converting html slides using `pagedown::chrome_print` to see if incremental bullets were split across slides by default and this didn't seem to work.  I've already opened and issue here  https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/issues/227, but should have started here first.  Will close the issue if somebody knows of a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Add this `css` code chunk anywhere in your slides (preferably as the last code chunk):

````
```{css, echo=FALSE}
@media print {
  .has-continuation {
    display: block;
  }
}
```
````

By default, incremental slides are hidden via `display: none;` in CSS. You can override this rule.

Comment: I saw this solution suggested in another SO thread, but it didn't work for me. I added this chunk in the default `xaringan-themer.css`, where there is already a `.remark-slide-scaler` call under `@media print`. But while the latter is showing in a different colour in RStudio, the former isn't, and the PDFs I generate using `pagedown::chrome_print()` merge the incremental slides into one. However, the `xaringanBuilder` method is working for me. Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

`xaringan::decktape(<html>, <pdf>)` supports this. See `?xaringan::decktape()` for more info.

```
---
title: ""
author: ""
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: solarized-light
    highlightLines: true
    countIncrementalSlides: false
---

# test

- test1

- test2

--

- test3

---
```

results in

[image]

Comment: How do we reference local `.html` files?  The solution above is ambiguous, and parsing also appears to be dependent on the user of Docker, at least in the `R` context.

Comment: Have you tried it and read the help file? No need for docker and local files work just fine.

Comment: Also I'd appreciate feedback what I can improve in my answer to not get downvoted for a working solution.

Comment: I have read the help. The reference is pointing at external files, and above, it's just skeleton code.  That said, are you suggesting that this command should work  `xaringan::decktape("01-assoc-rules.html", "test.pdf", docker=F)` when the knitted RMD document was output as `01-assoc-rules.html` in my current working directory?  If so, I will post a bug report, but my point above is that I was trying all sorts of combinations of docker, no docker trying to figure out the requirements to get this parsed.  Overall I am excited for this prospect and I am sure your feature is great.

Comment: It works if you have a working installation of `docker` or a local `decktape` installation. This is also clearly documented in the help of `xaringan::decktape()` as already stated in my answer.